# How to get next entry by date in matrix block but limit to just 1

Tags: matrix, craft-pro

I need to display a block from a matrix for the following week.

Basically the query I need to build is

```
{% for block in workshop.workshopSession.where(sessionDate > now).first() %}
```

I just can't quite get this to work and have been searching for a while. Perhaps I am just missing something obvious. There will be more than one entry with a date greater than "now" so I need to limit it to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
{% for block in workshop.workshopSession.sessionDate('>=' ~ now|date('Y-m-d')).limit(1) %}
```

If not you always can go with a "dirty" fix by just showing the `{% loop.first %}`